# HTML - divs outside of max-width

Tags: html, css, dom

I have ths code:

```html
 <style type="text/css">
      .product_page {
        height: 297mm !important;
        min-height: 297mm !important;
        max-height: 297mm !important;
        width: 210mm !important;
        max-width: 210mm !important;
        min-width: 210mm !important;
    background: green;
      }
      .product_header {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 17mm !important;
        background: #000;
      }
      .product_footer {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 10mm !important;
        background: #000;
        
    
      }
      .product_box {
        margin: 5mm !important;
        width: 200mm !important;
        min-width: 200mm !important;
        max-width: 200mm !important;
        height: 260mm !important;
        min-height: 260mm !important;
        max-height: 260mm !important;
        background: yellow;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    
      }
      .product_item {
        width: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        min-width: 50% !important;
        height: 75mm !important;
        min-height: 75mm !important;
        max-height: 75mm !important;
        background: #ccc;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
    
      }
      .product_photo {
        width: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        min-width: 50% !important;
        height: 75mm !important;
        min-height: 75mm !important;
        max-height: 75mm !important;
        background: red;
        display: inline-block;
        
      }
      .product_info {
        width: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        min-width: 50% !important;
        height: 75mm !important;
        min-height: 75mm !important;
        max-height: 75mm !important;
        background: pink;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    
    </style>
    
    <div class="product_page">
      <div class="product_header"></div>
      <div class="product_box">
        
          <div class="product_item">
            <div class="product_photo"></div>
            <div class="product_info"></div>
          </div>
         
         <div class="product_item">
            <div class="product_photo"></div>
            <div class="product_info"></div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="product_item">
            <div class="product_photo"></div>
            <div class="product_info"></div>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      <div class="product_footer"></div>
    </div>
```

[image]

As you can see 3rd product_item class is outside of max-width  - which is 200mm ... WHy? How to fix that?

Comment: 3x50% = 150% > 100%

Comment: the same when I put width 100mm ...

Comment: and the same logic: 3x100mm = 300mm > 200mm

Comment: ok, but I need it below... like on twitter bootstrap when I add col-md-6 + col-md-6 + col-md-6 the last class goes below - not in the next of div

Comment: flex-wrap:wrap;

Comment: I got this https://www.screencast.com/t/5X3LF14we which is not correct